# Azure Source Control Deployment not running my latest Code First Migration

Tags: entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-migrations, azure-deployment

I have an Azure website being deployed using the source control deployment and am using EF Code First Migrations to manage my database schemas.  Everything is set up and appears to be functioning properly and it deploys without errors, but there are only 4 migrations in my migration table in the database and there should be 5.  My application is also throwing the following error when I try to hit the database

```
The model backing the 'dbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).
```

indicating not all of the migrations have been run.  Is there somewhere on Azure I can look to see more detailed log files on the deployment and does anyone know why the migrations would run locally but not on azure?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your db context contructor:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Data.Migrations.Configuration>());
```

note: change "MyContext" to the name of your context.